# mouse click event new figure with subplot data

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseclick-event

I have several subplot in one figure and I would like to create a mouse event (double click) such that when a subplot is clicked a new figure is opened with just that plot, i.e. a sort of zoom

[image]

I incorporated your solution into my code.. the mouse event doesn't work yet.
Can it be that it has to do with the fact that I recursivelly create axes?

```
def plot_time_traces(diag_json,pulselist,save=False):
"""
this routines plots time traces of JET diagnostics

uses as input JSON file that contains info on the diagnostic the user wants
to plot and info on how to plot them (i.e. what window, linestyle, marker...)



:param diag_json: standard set containing the diagnostic the user wants to plot
:param pulselist: list of pulses (and colors)
:return:
"""
logging.info('using standard set {}'.format(diag_json))

logging.info('pulselist {}'.format(pulselist))


default = True
fold = './standard_set/'
with open(fold+diag_json, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # Remove comments from input json
    with open(fold+"temp.json", 'w') as wf:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line[0:2] == '//' or line[0:1] == '#':
                continue
            wf.write(line)

with open(fold+"temp.json", 'r') as f:
    input_dict = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    os.remove(fold+'temp.json')

try:
    ppflen = (len(input_dict['ppf']))
except:
    ppflen = 0
try:
    jpflen = (len(input_dict['jpf']))
except:
    jpflen = 0
totsignal = (ppflen + jpflen)
logging.info('reading {} signals'.format(str(totsignal)))
try:
    iColumn = int(input_dict['icolumn'])
    iRow = int(input_dict['irow'])
    linewidth = float(input_dict['linewidth'])
    markersize = float(input_dict['markersize'])
    default = False
except:
    iColumn = 4
    iRow = int(round(totsignal / iColumn))
    linewidth = 0.5
    markersize =  1

logging.debug('subplot {} x {}'.format(str(iRow),str(iColumn)))




units = []
names = []
dataname = []
pulse_list = []
time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
path = '/u/bviola/work/Python/EDGE2D/exp_data'
fig = plt.figure()


fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
t = Toggle()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", t.toggle)
for index,element in enumerate(pulselist):


    pulse = int(pulselist[index][0])
    pulse_list.append(pulse)

    logging.info('\n')
    logging.info('reading data for pulse %s ', pulse)

    indexSubPlot = 0

    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        for value in input_dict[key]:


            system=key
            node=value
            # print(value)



            if system == 'ppf':
                user=node.split('/')[0]
                ppfuid(user, "r")
                dda=node.split('/')[1]
                dtype=node.split('/')[2]

                # logging.debug('reading data %s ', key + '_' + dda + '_' + dtype)

                data_name = 'data_' + key + '_' + dda + '_' + dtype
                time_name = 't_data_' + key + '_' + dda + '_' + dtype
                unit_name = 'units_' + '_' + dda + '_' + dtype

                vars()[data_name], x, vars()[time_name], nd, nx, nt, vars()[
                    unit_name], xunits, tunits, desc, comm, seq, ier = \
                    ppfdata(pulse, dda, dtype, seq=0, uid=user,
                            device="JET", fix0=0, reshape=0, no_x=0, no_t=0)
                if ier == 0 :
                    logging.info('read data %s ', key + '_' + dda + '_' + dtype + 'seq {}'.format(str(seq)))
                else:
                    logging.info('no data')


                if default == True:
                    indexSubPlot = indexSubPlot + 1
                    ax_name = 'ax_' + str(indexSubPlot)
                    marker = 'x'
                    linestyle = ':'
                    logging.debug('using default options for ppf')

                else:
                    indexSubPlot = int(input_dict[system][value][0])
                    ax_name = 'ax_' + str(input_dict[system][value][0])
                    marker = input_dict[system][value][1]
                    linestyle = input_dict[system][value][2]
                    logging.debug('using JSON options for ppf')


                # vars()[indexSubPlot] = fig.add_subplot(iRow, iColumn, indexSubPlot)
                if indexSubPlot == 1:
                    ax_1 = plt.subplot(iRow, iColumn, indexSubPlot)
                else:
                    vars()[ax_name] = plt.subplot(iRow, iColumn,indexSubPlot,sharex=ax_1)

                plt.plot(vars()[time_name], vars()[data_name],
                             label=str(pulse) + ' ' + node, marker = marker, linestyle=linestyle, linewidth=linewidth,
                         markersize=markersize)
                plt.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 6})
                plt.xlabel('time[s]')
                plt.ylabel(vars()[
                    unit_name])
                # plt.hold(True)

            if system == 'jpf':
                data_name = 'data_' + key + '_' + value
                time_name = 't_data_' + key + '_' + value
                unit_name = 'units_' + key + '_' + value



                vars()[data_name], vars()[time_name], IplSigLen, IplSigTitle, vars()[
                    unit_name], ier = getdat.getdat(value,pulse)
                if ier == 0 :
                    logging.info('read data  ' + key + '_' + value )
                else:
                    logging.info('no data')





                if default == True:
                    indexSubPlot = indexSubPlot + 1
                    ax_name = 'ax_' + str(indexSubPlot)
                    marker = 'x'
                    linestyle = ':'
                    logging.debug('using default options for ppf')

                else:
                    indexSubPlot = int(input_dict[system][value][0])
                    ax_name = 'ax_' + str(input_dict[system][value][0])
                    marker = input_dict[system][value][1]
                    linestyle = input_dict[system][value][2]
                    logging.debug('used JSON options for jpf')




                if indexSubPlot == 1:
                    ax_1 = plt.subplot(iRow, iColumn,indexSubPlot)

                else:
                    vars()[ax_name] = plt.subplot(iRow, iColumn,
                                                       indexSubPlot,sharex=ax_1)
                plt.plot(vars()[time_name], vars()[data_name],
                             label=str(pulse) + ' ' + value, marker = marker, linestyle=linestyle, linewidth=linewidth,
                         markersize=markersize)

                plt.legend(loc='best', prop={'size': 6})
                # plt.ylabel(IplSigTitle)
                plt.ylabel(vars()[
                               unit_name])
                plt.xlabel('time[s]')



logging.info('plot DONE')
gs = GridSpec(1, 1)

# fig.tight_layout()
if save is True:
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    pulses = "-".join(str(n) for n in pulse_list)

    fname = diag_json[:-5]+'_'+pulses

    plt.savefig('figures/' + fname+'.png', format='png', dpi=300)

    logging.info('picture saved to {}'.format(cwd+os.sep+'figures/'+fname))
```

Comment: That would be a pretty neat effect. What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Doesn't sound too hard. The [event handling](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) documentation is pretty thorough. Once you have your event and a location, you can figure out which graph to plot in a new window. As above - what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The [matplotlib event handling tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) gives a good introduction into events. Here, I see two options:

### Create new figure on click

You can create a figure inside a callback to a `button_press_event`. Depending on which axes has been clicked you may recreate the same plot inside the new figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def create_plot(num, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,101)
    ax.plot(t, np.sin(num*t), label="Label {}".format(num))
    ax.legend()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,4)

for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    create_plot(i, ax=ax)


def create_fig(evt):
    if evt.inaxes:
        newfig, newax = plt.subplots()
        num = fig.axes.index(evt.inaxes)
        create_plot(num, ax=newax)
        newfig.show()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", create_fig)

plt.show()
```

### Zoom within the Figure.

You may perform all actions within the same figure. The idea would be, once a click occurs to, set all but the clicked axes invisible and make the clicked axes fill the entire subplotgrid's space. Another click on the single axes, turns all axes visible again and positions the axes back to its original position. The advantage is that you do not need to recreate any plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,4)

for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.plot(np.arange(20), np.cumsum(np.random.randn(20)), label="Label {}".format(i))
    ax.legend()

gs = GridSpec(1,1)

class Toggle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_visible = True
        self.opos = None

    def toggle(self,evt):
        if evt.inaxes:
            if self.all_visible:
                for ax in fig.axes:
                    if ax != evt.inaxes:
                        ax.set_visible(False)
                self.opos = evt.inaxes.get_position()
                evt.inaxes.set_position(gs[0].get_position(fig))
                self.all_visible=False
            else:
                for ax in fig.axes:
                    ax.set_visible(True)

                evt.inaxes.set_position(self.opos)
                self.all_visible = True
                self.opos = None
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

t = Toggle()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", t.toggle)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I applied your solution to my case, it doesn't work.